# How to fetch collaboration repos GitHub API?

Tags: api, github, repository

I wonder if there is a way to fetch the repos of which I'm a collaborator with the GitHub API v3?
Some of my mates have a repo where I helped and I'd like to fetch those as well.

Comment: are you not getting the repos when you call the repositories endpoint?

Comment: I'm getting mine, not the ones of my mates in which I took part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this API (GitHub API v3)
Get credentials: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/editing-a-github-apps-permissions , then

Step 1. Get all of your friends' repositories (with `owner` role)

Step 2. Have a for loop.
Check you is collaborator of per repository. https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#check-if-a-user-is-a-repository-collaborator

You must use GitHub API and programming a little.

Comment: But then, I need to fetch the repo's of my mates just to filter out in which I helped?

Comment: step 1: list all repositories of your friends, step 2: loop, check your contributor in per repository. Must coding few lines of code.